# Unable to read HTML content

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-crawler, urllib2

I'm building a webCrawler which needs to read links inside a webpage. For which I'm using urllib2 library of python to open and read the websites.

I found a website where I'm unable to fetch any data.
The URL is "http://www.biography.com/people/michael-jordan-9358066"

My code,

```
import urllib2

response = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.biography.com/people/michael-jordan-9358066")
print response.read()
```

By running the above code, the content I get from the website, if I open it in a browser and the content I get from the above code is very different. The content from the above code does not include any data.

I thought it could be because of delay in reading the web page, so I introduced a delay. Even after the delay, the response is the same.

```
response = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.biography.com/people/michael-jordan-9358066")
time.sleep(20)
print response.read()
```

The web page opens perfectly fine in a browser.

However, the above code works fine for reading Wikipedia or some other websites.
I'm unable to find the reason behind this odd behaviour. Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that the site you visit detects User-Agent in the http header. If so, setting User-Agent will make it work.

Comment: I think maybe all data are loaded by js, so you cannot find any content in the html page.

Comment: @WKPlus: I tried adding User agent as firefox, the response is still the same.

Comment: The page is created dynamically, not as a html loaded from the server. Use selenium instead.

Comment: @wh0 So it seems that the data is loaded by javascript as 郑福真 said. You can use selenium, or figure out which url javascript use to load data and then just open that url to fetch data. For requesting a url in python, I prefer `requests` than `urllib2`.

Answer (score 3):

What you are experiencing is most likely to be the effect of [dynamic web pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_web_page). These pages do not have static content for `urllib` or `requests` to get. The data is loaded on site. You can use Python's [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to solve this.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I have just checked the page and its entire content is generated dynamically.

Comment: If you can figure out which url javascript use to load data, maybe you can just open that url to fetch data, no need for selenium which I think it's not efficient enough.